# How to show fixed-effects coefficients in Stata?

Tags: time-series, stata, fixed-effects-model

I am estimating a fixed-effects model on a panel-data using the `xtreg, fe` command. I hope to show fixed-effects coefficients in the table as well.
Can anyone tell me how to exercise the option for showing fixed-effects coefficients in Stata? Thank you very much!